# Scala to Java migration method definition not clear

Tags: java, scala

In order to reduce the number of technologies used in one of the projects I'm working on I'm trying to migrate few Scala classes to Java. Totally inexperienced in Scala I'm trying to convert this method:

```
private val subscriptionStore = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, Promise[PushMessage]]()

def subscribe[T](msgType: PushMessageType, callerId: String, ctx: Context)(parser: PushMessage => T): Future[T] = {
    val notificationPromise = Promise[PushMessage]
    subscriptionStore.put(toKey(callerId, msgType.notificationString), notificationPromise)
    notificationPromise.future.map(parser(_))(VertxExecutionContext.apply(ctx))
}
```

My current Java version

```
private ConcurrentHashMap<String, CompletableFuture<PushMessage>> subscriptionStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public CompletableFuture<PushMessage> subscribe(PushMessageType msgType, String callerId, Context ctx) {
    CompletableFuture<PushMessage> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    return subscriptionStore.put(toKey(correlationId, msgType.notificationString), future);
}
```

`toKey` returns a String value

My main issue is the method declaration

```
def subscribe[T](msgType: PushMessageType, callerId: String, ctx: Context)(parser: PushMessage => T): Future[T]
```

Any suggestion?

Many thanks

Comment: if possible migrate java classes to scala

Comment: Not sure what's tripping you up. Two argument lists can just be concatenated into one. `PushMessage => T` is `Function<PushMessage,T>` ... What else?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form (not the purest functional form) is without multiple parameter lists, i.e. convert

```
def subscribe[T](msgType: PushMessageType, callerId: String, ctx: Context)(parser: PushMessage => T): Future[T]
```

to

```
def subscribe[T](msgType: PushMessageType, callerId: String, ctx: Context, parser: PushMessage => T): Future[T]
```

to pass the parser function in Java 8, you can do something like this:

```
import java.util.function.*;

class FunctionTest {

    public static Integer subscribe(String msgType, Function<String,Integer> parser) {
        return parser.apply(msgType);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Function<String,Integer> parserImpl = (a) -> a.length();
        System.out.println(subscribe(args[0], parserImpl));
    }
}
```

Comment: unless you are using partially applied functions, it could work

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd say that `subscribe` method that uses `Future` in Scala (i.e. something that can be fired only once) sounds suspicious to me. It would be really much easier to help you, if you provided more context on how this method is used and who/when/how fires (resolves) the `Promise`s.

For now let's assume that you want to translate Scala code as closely as possible to Java. To do this let's first understand what Scala code does.

```scala
def subscribe[T](msgType: PushMessageType, callerId: String, ctx: Context)(parser: PushMessage => T): Future[T] = {
    val notificationPromise = Promise[PushMessage]
    subscriptionStore.put(toKey(callerId, msgType.notificationString), notificationPromise)
    notificationPromise.future.map(parser(_))(VertxExecutionContext.apply(ctx))
}
```

First signature

```scala
def subscribe[T](msgType: PushMessageType, callerId: String, ctx: Context)(parser: PushMessage => T): Future[T] = {
```

It means that this is a "partially applied" method i.e. this is effectively a method with 4 arguments: `msgType`, `callerId`, `ctx`, and `parser` but you call it using to set of brackets such as `subscribe(msgType, callerId, ctx)(parser)`. The important part here is that in Scala you can do something like this:

```scala
val partialApplication = subscribe(msgType, callerId, ctx)

// much later or in a different place

val future = partialApplication(parser)
```

Note that if this feature is not used in Scala for `subscribe` you can safely merge arguments into one set and get much simpler Java code as @motilio suggests. I'll assume that you really need this partial application usage. IMHO, the simplest way so simulate the same behavior in Java is to have a method that returns a `java.util.Function`.

Now the body of the `subscribe`:

```scala
    val notificationPromise = Promise[PushMessage]
    subscriptionStore.put(toKey(callerId, msgType.notificationString), notificationPromise)
    notificationPromise.future.map(parser(_))(VertxExecutionContext.apply(ctx))
```

We create a `notificationPromise` which is similar to `ComputableFuture` and put it into `subscriptionStore`. And then we return a different `Future` that is calculated as result of the future inside `notificationPromise` modified by applying `parser` lambda to it, and execute that on an `Executor` specified by call to `VertxExecutionContext.apply(ctx)`.

So reasonably similar code in Java would be something like this:

```java
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, CompletableFuture<PushMessage>> subscriptionStore = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public <T> Function<Function<PushMessage, T>, CompletableFuture<T>> subscribeLikeScala(PushMessageType msgType, String callerId, Context ctx) {
    CompletableFuture<PushMessage> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    subscriptionStore.put(toKey(callerId, msgType.notificationString), future);
    return fn -> future.thenApplyAsync(fn, new Executor() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Runnable command) {
            ctx.runOnContext(ignore -> command.run());
        }
    });
}
```

Custom `Executor` implementation here is based on [VertxExecutionContext](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-lang-scala/blob/master/vertx-lang-scala/src/main/scala/io/vertx/lang/scala/VertxExecutionContext.scala) Scala source.

And usage example might be something like (obviously just returning `hashCode` is a stupid `parser` but this is an example):

```java
Function<Function<PushMessage, Integer>, CompletableFuture<Integer>> partialApplication = subscribeLikeScala(msgType, callerId, ctx);

// much later or in a different place

CompletableFuture<Integer> future = partialApplication.apply(msg -> msg.hashCode());
```

The fact that you need to specify type of the parser at the moment you call `subscribe` rather than `apply` might be either a plus or a minus depending on what you need. Given how easy it is actually to apply transformation to `ComputableFuture` in Java using `thenApplyAsync`, it might be OK to just use your signature and left application of the `parser` to the caller. The only thing that you loose here is a control over which executor will be used to apply parser which might or might not be important for you. But beware that your logic with

```
return subscriptionStore.put(toKey(correlationId, msgType.notificationString), future);
```

seems like almost 100% bug because `ConcurrentHashMap.put` returns the ***previous*** value stored under the same key which is almost definitely not what you want and surely not what Scala code did.

Lastly and getting back to what I started with, subscription that can be fired only once is really strange and is possibly a bad hack. Your usage scenario might be covered much better by RxJava [Observable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html). I strongly encourage you considering it in your context.